# Undefined item in each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, undefined, each

The following code has a jquery each statement that goes through a div.faq containing h1,h2 h3,h4. According to my logic (which fails me right now) the code supposed to run through the div select all Header elements and then make the h1/h2 a list item, and h3/h4 a sublist item. For some reason I keep getting a "undefined" element before each sublist starts.

```
//Declare everything
var sidebar = "";
var sidebar_header = new Array();
var sidebar_items = new Array();
var i = 0;

//Select all elements
$(".faq h3,.faq h4,.faq h1,.faq h2").each(function(index, value){

    // Add an ID to each element
    $(this).attr("id", "item-" + index);

    //If element is h1 or element is h2
    if($(this).is("h1") || $(this).is("h2")){

        sidebar_header[i] = "<li><a href='#item-" + index + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</a>";

        i++;
    //If element is h3 or is h4
    }else if($(this).is("h3") || $(this).is("h4")){

        sidebar_items[i - 1] += "<li><a href='#item-" + index + "'>" + $(this).text() +" </a></li>";

    }


});


var total = i;

//Loop through all list items and add sub list items
for(i=0;i<total;i++){

    sidebar += sidebar_header[i] + "<ul>" + sidebar_items[i] + "</ul></li>";

}

//Append
$(".side").append("<ul>" + sidebar + "</ul>");
```

Everything "works" except that my result is:

```
List item 1
 - Undefined
 - Sub List item 1
 - Sub List item 2
 - Sub List item 3

List item 2
 - Undefined
 - Sub List item 1
 - Sub List item 2
```

I can't tell what's undefined. Everything was declared. I am just adding items to already defined arrays. I ran several console.log on different parts of the code and the issue seems to be here:

```
sidebar_items[i - 1] += "<li><a href='#item-" + index + "'>" + $(this).text() +" </a></li>";
```

But I can't figure out why. Suggestions are welcomed!

UPDATE:

Sample link: http://jsfiddle.net/pgw47ecb/

Comment: Please give a jsfiddle working. Need HTML to reproduce the case and determine the failure.

Comment: Can you please put a `console.log(this)` in the loop body and post what it logs?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pgw47ecb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're concatenating a string onto an Array index that has no value (well, it has the value of `undefined`). Javascript is happily casting `undefined` to a string and doing the concatenation, so you wind up with `"undefined" + '<li>...</li>'` the first time you attempt to add your new HTML to that index.

You'll need to initialize each index of `sidebar_items` to an empty string first (or not use string concatenation if the value of that index is not defined).

```
$(".faq h3,.faq h4,.faq h1,.faq h2").each(function(index, value){

// Add an ID to each element
$(this).attr("id", "item-" + index);

//If element is h1 or element is h2
if($(this).is("h1") || $(this).is("h2")){

    sidebar_header[i] = "<li><a href='#item-" + index + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</a>";

    i++;
//If element is h3 or is h4
}else if($(this).is("h3") || $(this).is("h4")){
    // Give this index a value: an empty string.
    if(typeof sidebar_items[i - 1] !== "string") sidebar_items[i - 1] = "";

     sidebar_items[i - 1] += "<li><a href='#item-" + index + "'>" + $(this).text() +" </a></li>";

}


});
```

Comment: This solved it. I thought I was concatenating the value inside the array, but not the array itself. Thank you!